# How to install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 14.04 by ansible?

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I want to install phpmyadmin on ubuntu 14.04 with ansible. I don't know how to answer in installation questions with ansible playbook!! I search a lot in this site and other sites but i found nothing !!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All config is stored either in the database or the config file. You will have to set both up as you require them.

The detailed procedure would probably be too much for a SO answer (and question in the first place). I'd suggest you set up WordPress once manually and then check out the generated config file as well as create a dump from the MySQL database. Then you can generate the config file with Ansibles [`template` module](http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html) and import your sql dump with the [`shell` module](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html), e.g. `mysql ... < data.sql` after transferring it with the [`copy` module](http://docs.ansible.com/copy_module.html)